# Receiving net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE with Nodejs Post Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, post

I'm trying to make a post request in my Node app; however, I am getting the following error.

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:27017/postDebate net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

How to resolve this?

Here is my route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Debate = require('../models/debate');
var mdb = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
  assert = require('assert');
var api_version = '1';
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/debate';

router.post('/'+api_version+'/postDebate', function(req, res, next) {
  var debate = new Debate(req.body);
  console.log(debate, "here is the debate");
  debate.save(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Debate saved successfully!');
  });
  res.json(debate);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And since I am invoking this route after onclick calling a function in my ejs file, here is my javascript file.

```
function postDebate() {
  var topic = document.getElementById('topic').value;
  var tags = document.getElementById('tags').value;
  var argument = document.getElementById('argument').value;

  var debateObject = {
    "topic": topic,
    "tags": tags,
    "argument": argument
  };
  console.log(topic, tags, argument);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(debateObject),
    contentType: "application/json",
        //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType:'json',
        url: 'http://localhost:27017/post',                      
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data), "This is the debateObject");                               
        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
}
```

**How do I resolve this error? What is the problem here?**

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:27017/postDebate net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? There are 2 weeks since I'm having this issue and everything I've tried is not working ... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add CORS headers on `app` level and you must to run res.end() on OPTIONS request

Then check your URL, you registered your module with some name so your URL should looks like `/ROUTER_MODULE_NAME/1/postDebate` but from your frontend you calling to `http://localhost:27017/post`

Here is minimal example which I checked and it works fine for me:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('request', req.url, req.body, req.method);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-token");
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.end();
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});

router.get('/hello', function(req, res, next) {
    res.end('hello world')
});

app.use('/router', router)

app.listen(8081)

//try in browser `$.get('http://127.0.0.1:8081/router/hello')`
```

Comment: Ah unfortunately no luck :/ any idea why?